# Операционная система для программирования Python\Django

Tags: python, django

Начинаю изучать python, пока изучаю python в pycharme на винде проблем особых нет.
Но на днях попытался установить Django на винду, не получилось известными способами.

Возник вопрос, на какой операционной системе лучше изучать и разрабатывать на python\django? Винда или Ubuntu? 
Или разницы нет?

Посоветуйте кто что знает, может лучше сразу на линукс перейти?

На какой операционке разарбатываете вы?

P.S. Помню когда хотел Ruby изучать, то там траблы были на винде с кодировкой и прочей ересью.

Comment: OS X. Серьезно

Comment: Конечно, переходите на линукс (или другой \*nix). / Дело тут в том, что разработчики самых первых версий всех этих продуктов писали в \*nix, а потом все портировалось в винду (думаю, частенько не самыми талантливыми прогерами).

Answer (score 4):

Всегда можно использовать Vagrant или другой подобный инструмент виртуализации.

Если не хочется виртуализации или не хватает мощностей, то на любом дистрибутиве linux или маках будет конечно удобнее. Но развернуть рабочую среду в Windows тоже не составит проблем.

Сам сейчас работаю на Windows. Через  [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) все необходимое ставиться за пару ентеров. И сборка Vim для собственно кода.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше работать на ОС которая понятна и где есть привычные инструменты для правки кода, а Django и прочее развернуть к примеру на виртуалке с Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 0):

В pycharm установка пакета выполняется в несколько кликов. Сам использую pycharm на windows и debian. Если у Вас не получилось установить django, это не повод менять ОС, это повод разобраться почему это произошло.

Answer (score 0):

Также начинал работать с питоном под виндой и линуксом на виртуалке, но после того как понял что 80% рабочего времени сижу в виртуалке снес винду и уже почти 5 лет сижу на убунте.
Линукс или макос в мире джанго и де юро и де факто